# Apache server how to use http://localhost instead of http://localhost/index.php

Tags: php, apache, http

i don't have a computer with apache to give more information at the moment but i'm creating a project about a page where users will be able to view and download some files(using php,http,css but i don't think this helps with my question). I can see the page using the url `http://localhost/index.php` . I saw someone else using apache  and he can see his page by writing just `http://localhost`(didn't have the chanse to ask him) . So i'm wondering, how can i see mine just writing `http://localhost` ?

Answer (score -2):

By default `index.php` gets loaded ,even if you don't write index.php (or many be with any extension like html,asp,jsp etc !).
Edit : I meant itfor similiar extension .php for php ,.html for html

Comment: -1 this is not the answer of the question.

Comment: -1: [It's not even true](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)